# SMARTY foreach array (sort order)

Tags: arrays, foreach, smarty

I run Prestashop 1.5 which uses SMARTY. When Quantity discounts are shown, they do not show in logical order.

I would like to arrange them in this order:

first 1 unit then
2 units then
3 units then
4 units then
5 units

Instead of in the order i added them, which is the case now. Can anoyone help?

Br,
Tobias

I have tried with |@array_reverse but it doens't seem to work...

CURRENT CODE:
................................
{if $quantity_discounts}
{foreach from=$quantity_discounts item='quantity_discount' name='quantity_discounts'}

xxxxx

{/foreach}
{/if}

Answer (score 1):

In Classes/specificprice.php 
On line #293:
Change:

```
ORDER BY `id_product_attribute` DESC, `from_quantity` DESC, `id_specific_price_rule` ASC, `score` DESC
```

Into:

```
ORDER BY `id_product_attribute` DESC, `from_quantity` ASC, `id_specific_price_rule` ASC, `score` DESC
```

Comment: You should copy the file and place it in the override/classes/ folder and make changes there